# Firebase onSnapshot limit download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore listener on my app that downloads items when they are added to the db. At a first time, it downloads all the documents (I am using onSnapshot) but I want to limit this to 12, because I have a FlatList that renders items when I scroll...

I think this will be a problem to download all the items at the first time if there are +1000 documents for example. I have thought to move from the listener to normal queries but I need it.

Any ideas?

```
 const unsuscribe = firebase
      .getDatabase()
      .collection("reviews")
      .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();

        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // Stuff
          }
        });
        // More Stuff
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) feature?

```
 const unsuscribe = firebase
      .getDatabase()
      .collection("reviews")
      .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .limit(12)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();

        changes.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // Stuff
          }
        });
        // More Stuff
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repurpose @RossHochwerts suggestion to use [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) in my query like this:

```js
useEffect(
    () => 
        onSnapshot(
            query(
                collection(db, 'matches', matchDetails.id, 'messages'),
                orderBy('timestamp', 'desc'),
                limit(1)
            ), snapshot => setLastMessage(snapshot.docs[0]?.data()?.message)
        ),
    [matchDetails, db]
);
```